# Nested Generic Events

Tags: c#, generics, events, delegates

I want to have a generic event that I can fire that will take a custom eventArgs> e

Here is my code so far

```
public event resultsEventHandler<T> returnResults;

public delegate void resultsEventHandler<T>(object sender, resultEventArgs<ObservableEntityCollection<T>> e);


protected virtual void OnreturnResults(resultEventArgs<ObservableEntityCollection<T>> > e)
{
    if (returnResults != null)
    {
        returnResults<T>(this, e);
    }
}

public class resultEventArgs<ObservableEntityCollection<T>> : EventArgs
{
    private readonly ObservableEntityCollection<T> _results;
    public resultEventArgs(ObservableEntityCollection<T>  results)
    {
        this._results = results;
    }

    public ObservableEntityCollection<T>>  queryResult 
    { 
        get { return _results; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I wish to have a an event which will pass an ObservableCollection<T> inside the eventArgs. I have over 140 types that T could be. I have build custom events, but I can't get the syntax correct to build the generic delegates etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the question but

```
public class resultEventArgs<ObservableEntityCollection<T>> : EventArgs
```

should be

```
public class resultEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
```

Comment: yeah, agreed with that, in one incarnation of my problem it was. I posted the highly messed up code rather than my first attempt.